# Was there an occasion when nazis turned their backs on a national anthem?

Tags: nazi-germany

Brexit party members today turned their backs during the playing of the EU anthem at the opening of the EU parliament. This was commented on in the [newspapers](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/live/2019/jul/02/tory-leadership-latest-news-hustings-boris-johnsons-brexit-plan-could-prove-fatal-to-tory-party-says-former-leader-william-hague-live-news). A below-the-line commenter there, `thelastnumber` wrote

> The brexit party aren't the first to protest an anthem by turning their backs.
>
> The nazis did it first.

Was there a noted occasion when nazis turned their backs on a national anthem in contempt?

Comment: Not to start a polemic but two elements: the european anthem is not a national anthem, and turning back is often used as mean of contestation (policemen did that to a president in France)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**They did turn their backs**, not on an anthem, but **on Fritz Löwenthal**, a speaker for the Communist party in the Reichstag in 1930.

[Twitter link](https://twitter.com/Otto_English/status/1146006459437715456/photo/1) with Alamy stock picture.

Comment: Thanks! But isn't the actual date 1930?

Comment: @emrys57: Correct, I didn't catch the comment further down the first time.

Comment: I wonder how we can be sure if it was indeed Mr. Löwenthal.

Comment: @Sprottenwels Why do you doubt that? (And what difference does it make, i.e. would it be relevant if it had been a different speaker?)

Comment: @DevSolar I doubt it because the speaker is not in the picture. And I think any such assumptions in a historical context ought to be avoided. The fact that the NSDAP members turned their back on anyone in the Reichstag is of course important and sheds light on the behaviour of its members. But I don't like to see unproven claims in this context.

Comment: @DevSolar Oh I also have this tendency to doubt anything that starts with "It's 100% true" and then does not provide any proof at all.

Comment: @Sprottenwels: [fullfact.org](https://fullfact.org/online/historic-picture-nazis-reichstag/) -- [Süddeutsche Zeitung Photo](https://www.sz-photo.de/?16607724099100603390&EVENT=POPUP&WINDOW=WGWINe4704873e01b6fac8cb1c19fdf7143a9&AJXUID=0.17695958908117593&MEDIANUMBER=00296919&MEDIAITEMS=bc9db72789c4078eb1c3dcf096151496c1d6b85f&OMG=b6aa8b5991c4&PAGING_SCOPE_4=1&MEDIAGROUP_SCOPE=1%5d) -- [Alamy](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-members-the-nsdap-in-the-reichstag-1930-36997280.html). I didn't see reason to doubt the source given in my answer to begin with.

Comment: @DevSolar thank you! that sure is a start!

Comment: I'd suggest that 'not on the anthem' should also be in bold, considering it's the really pertinent point.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons Debatable, both whether the current boldface is insufficient ("they did turn their backs on a person, not an anthem"), and whether that's less of an affront or more. I prefer it the way it is, in no small part because it leaves the "better or worse" part to be judged by the reader. I would not want to have to come up with a "yes or no" answer to this Q.

Comment: @DevSolar not sure I agree, but it's your answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

Prior to 1922, there was no official hymn.
In 1922, ["Das Lied der Deutschen"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschlandlied) became the national anthem, thanks to president Ebert (it's third verse remains to be the German national anthem to this day).

The NSDAP bore no contempt towards this anthem. In fact, it was, at least in part, played during such occasions as the [Sportpalast speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sportpalast_speech) by Joseph Goebbels. The NS regime kept the Deutschlandlied but also established the [Horst-Wessel-Lied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horst-Wessel-Lied) as a co-anthem.

Therefore, I do not see why any Nazi should have turned their back on the German anthem. I can't say for sure, though, that this was never the case with any anthem at all.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that too, but I still wonder if someone will come up with a counterexample. I seem to remember that everyone was respectful of anthems at the 1936 Olympics, even if reluctantly.

Comment: @emrys57 I only now realize that you were asking about anthems in general, not only the German anthem. This renders my answer more or less pointless, of course.

Comment: Not at all pointless! But it is predictable, and depressing, that a piece of fake news like the original comment gets dozens of upvotes in the time it takes to find that it is false. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The original below-the-line comment, its 31 upvotes and two supportive response comments, can be seen at https://www.theguardian.com/politics/live/2019/jul/02/tory-leadership-latest-news-hustings-boris-johnsons-brexit-plan-could-prove-fatal-to-tory-party-says-former-leader-william-hague-live-news#comment-130672617

Comment: For the record: all three stanzas of the "Deutschlandlied" are officially the national anthem of Germany, but the first two stanzas is not normally performed in public.

Comment: @fdb that is not correct. As of 1991, only the third stanza is the anthem. See https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/nhbrfbek/index.html

Comment: @Sprottenwels. Thank you for the reference. You are right.